# Unpack uncertain number of attributes from iterator object in Boto DynamoDB Scan

Tags: python, iterator, generator, amazon-dynamodb, boto

So I am using AWS DynamoDB because of the NoSQL-ness and the ability to have an ambiguous number of 'columns' so to speak. For this I am using boto to interface with the database, but getting back the different number of columns/attributes dynamically is proving difficult.

My db table is mostly without a definitive schema (why I'm going with NoSQL) and most rows will have attributes different from other rows. I know Dynamo can do this, but I need a way to get all keys/columns/attributes with a simple scan. My database is not large and will not grow much at all so I'm not worried about the efficiency of scan/query.

My table (more or less):

```
{'name': 'John',    'email': '12@34.com'}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'email': '34@56.com', 'dislikes': 'people's knees'}
{'name': 'Joe',     'email': '78@90.com', 'hobby':    'golf'}
```

As you can see, there are different attributes for each row.

My testing script for boto

```
import os
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")


def connect():
    conn = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(
        'us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    return conn

conn = connect()

table = Table('table1', connection=conn)

scan = table.scan()
```

This returns an iterator object

```
<boto.dynamodb2.items.Item object at ....>
```

To parse through this object, one must know the attribute names and the object cannot be indexed by numbers:

```
for i in scan:
    print i['name']
    # John
    # Charlie
    # Joe

for i in scan:
    print i[0]
    # None
    # None
    # None
```

And when I use multiple variables for unpacking, it works, but I have to define the variables specifically like this:

```
for i, j, k in scan:
        print i, j, k
```

Which works for rows with three columns but only three.

What I want to be able to do is loop through each row and get its corresponding columns back, which will probably be different than the next rows. I have hit a wall and any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

So I feel pretty dumb. A key part of this answer is .items() called on the scan. That allowed the scan to actually be iterated over in the way I wanted it to.

I wanted a dictionary of various-sized dictionaries so I needed to create a wider-scoped dictionary to hold each row/person and a more narrow scope to add each detail (key/column and its value). Your data structure might be different than mine but this hopefully gets you pointed in the right direction.

```
...

scan = table.scan()

#outer-most dict for each row
dict0 = {}

# enumerate so each row can be appended to dict0 using index 
for index, row in enumerate(scan):
    # inner-most dict for each key/value pair
    dict1 = {}
    for key, value in row.items():
        dict1[str(key)] = str(value)
    dict0[index] = dict1
```

I used str() because I was getting unicode u' ' characters in my results.

Iterating back over the data is mostly the same, we're just leaving out the dictionary stuff.

```
for index, keyValues in dict0.items():
    print index
    for key, value in keyValues.items():
        print "\t {}: {}".format(key, value)
```

Prints out something like this (sorted by time added):

```
0
    "hobby": "golf"
    "email": "78@90.com"
    "name" : "Joe"
1
    'dislikes': "people's knees"
    "name" : "Charlie"
    "email": "34@56.com"
2
    "name" : "John"
    "email": "12@34.com"
```